# How to serialize data to unserialize in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization

I have stored location info in my users table. Now I want to `unserialize` that data. See below my code:

```
//$seri = $getUser['location_info'];
$seri = 'a:8:{s:4:"city";s:6:"Novska";s:6:"region";s:27:"Sisacko-Moslavacka Zupanija";s:7:"country";s:2:"HR";s:12:"country_name";s:7:"Croatia";s:14:"continent_code";s:2:"EU";s:10:"ip_address";s:10:"5.43.160.0";s:13:"currency_code";s:3:"HRK";s:15:"currency_symbol";s:12:"kn";}';
$unseri = unserialize($seri);
var_dump($unseri); exit; //Output: bool(false)
```

When unserialize I got `bool(false)` Please help

*Edit*: I need country name `Croatia`. If above code is not possible could you please share me alternative solution to get country name.

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php): '*In case the passed string is not unserializeable, FALSE is returned and E_NOTICE is issued.*'. Is that all your code?

Comment: A mutation on that serialised data can break it.

Comment: Did you hand-roll that serialisation? `s:12:"kn"` < that states that the string should be 12 characters long, not 2. Change it to `s:2:"kn"` and it works fine.

Comment: I have checked. `"kn"` looking `&#107;&#110;` so length is 12.

Comment: @Developer - those are HTML encoded versions of the characters, what you've got serialized isn't that. You literally have the 2-character string `kn` encoded there. Switch on error reporting and I bet you'll get `unserialize(): Error at offset 257 of 266 bytes`

Comment: Yes I got error. Thanks @CD001

Answer (score -1):

PHP serialize() unserialize() usage

http://freeonlinetools24.com/serialize

**Example:**

// say you have an array something like this

```
$multidimentional_array= array(
array(
    array("rose", 1.25, 15),
    array("daisy", 0.75, 25),
    array("orchid", 4, 7) 
   ),
array(
    array("rose", 1.25, 15),
    array("daisy", 0.75, 25),
    array("orchid", 5, 7) 
   ),
array(
    array("rose", 1.25, 15),
    array("daisy", 0.75, 25),
    array("orchid", 8, 7) 
)
);
```

// serialize

```
 $serialized_array=serialize($multidimentional_array);
 print_r($serialized_array);
```

Which gives you an output something like this

```
a:3:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"rose";i:1;d:1.25;i:2;i:15;}i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:5:"daisy";i:1;d:0.75;i:2;i:25;}i:2;a:3:{i:0;s:6:"orchid";i:1;i:4;i:2;i:7;}}i:1;a:3:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"rose";i:1;d:1.25;i:2;i:15;}i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:5:"daisy";i:1;d:0.75;i:2;i:25;}i:2;a:3:{i:0;s:6:"orchid";i:1;i:5;i:2;i:7;}}i:2;a:3:{i:0;a:3:{i:0;s:4:"rose";i:1;d:1.25;i:2;i:15;}i:1;a:3:{i:0;s:5:"daisy";i:1;d:0.75;i:2;i:25;}i:2;a:3:{i:0;s:6:"orchid";i:1;i:8;i:2;i:7;}}}
```

again if you want to get the original array back just use PHP unserialize() function

```
$original_array=unserialize($serialized_array);
var_export($original_array);
```